# Not passing all optional arguments in apply

Tags: r, function

I am facing some problem with the apply function passing on arguments to a function when not needed. I understand that apply don't know what to do with the optional arguments and just pass them on the function.

But anyhow, here is what I would like to do:

First I want to specify a list of functions that I would like to use.

```
functions <- list(length, sum)
```

Then I would like to create a function which apply these specified functions on a data set.

```
myFunc <- function(data, functions) {
  for (i in 1:length(functions)) print(apply(X=data, MARGIN=2, FUN=functions[[i]]))
}
```

This works fine.

```
data <- cbind(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
myFunc(data, functions)

[1] 100 100
[1] -0.5758939 -5.1311173
```

But I would also like to use additional arguments for some functions, e.g.

```
power <- function(x, p) x^p
```

Which don't work as I want to. If I modify `myFunc` to:

```
myFunc <- function(data, functions, ...) {
  for (i in 1:length(functions)) print(apply(X=data, MARGIN=2, FUN=functions[[i]], ...))
}
```

`functions` as

```
functions <- list(length, sum, power)
```

and then try my function I get

```
myFunc(data, functions, p=2)

Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : 
  2 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1
```

How may I solve this issue?

Sorry for the wall of text. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Curry` from `functional` to fix the parameter you want, put the function in the list of function you want to apply and finally iterate over this list of functions:

```
library(functional)

power <- function(x, p) x^p 
funcs = list(length, sum, Curry(power, p=2), Curry(power, p=3))
lapply(funcs, function(f) apply(data, 2 , f))
```

With your code you can use:

```
functions <- list(length, sum, Curry(power, p=2))
myFunc(data, functions)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd advocate using Colonel's `Curry` approach, but if you want to stick to base R you can always:

```
funcs <- list(length, sum, function(x) power(x, 2))
```

which is roughly what `Curry` ends up doing

Answer (score 0):

One option is to pass the parameters in a list with the arguments needed for each function.  You can add those parameters to the others needed for `apply` using `c` and then use `do.call` to call the function. Something like this. I also wrap all the output in a list here rather than using `print`; your usage may vary.

```
power <- function(x, p) x^p 
myFunc <- function(data, functions, parameters) {
  lapply(seq_along(functions), function(i) {
      p0 <- list(X=data, MARGIN=2, FUN=functions[[i]])
      do.call(apply, c(p0, parameters[[i]]))
  })
}

d <- matrix(1:6, nrow=2)
functions <- list(length, sum, power)
parameters <- list(NULL, NULL, p=3)
myFunc(d, functions, parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lazyeval package:

```
library(lazyeval)


my_evaluate <- function(data, expressions, ...) {
  lapply(expressions, function(e) {
    apply(data, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(x) {
      lazy_eval(e, c(list(x=x), list(...))) 
    })
  })
}
```

And use it like this:

```
my_expressions <- lazy_dots(sum = sum(x), sumpow = sum(x^p), length_k = length(x)*k )
data <- cbind(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
my_evaluate(data, my_expressions, p = 2, k = 2)
```